# Ubuntu Gnome fails to install

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, ubuntu-gnome

I have made a Ubuntu Gnome dvd to install from so I could try the gnome DE. So when I booted into the ISO I started a live session, and then decided to install Ubuntu Gnome. I went through the installation process like normal but then I got an error saying that if failed to make a swap partition in the partition /dev/sda3. I thought it might be an issue with ubiquity being able to delete/reformat the swap partition. So I exited the ISO and booted into an Arch Linux install DVD and entered cfdisk to find that there were no partitions on my hard drive. So I exited the Arch ISO and reentered the Ubuntu Gnome CD and it kept failing the automatic login. My hardware is a custom computer with the following

- AMD A6-5600K with ATI graphics
- ASRock FM2A58M-VG3+ Motherboard
- 8GB of DDR3 Ram
- Seagate 1TB hard drive

Comment: Never Mind I decided to go with an installation of Fedora 24 instead. The anaconda installer worked seamlessly with my hardware and the repos are way more up to date than Ubuntu's